# probability doubt

Tags: probability

I have a doubt in this question.

From a set of $n$ items a random sample of size $k$  is to be selected .What is the probability a given item will be among the $k$ selected?

I just know that here number of exhaustive cases is $C_n^k$, but  how to compute the favourable cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The favourable cases are: Do pick the special item (no choice), then pick $k-1$ out of the remaining $n-1$ items ($n-1\choose k-1$ possible choices). The final result from simplifying $\frac{n-1\choose k-1}{n\choose k}$ should not be surprising.

Answer (score 4):

This is much, much simpler: the probability of finding a specific item in a random draw of $k$ items from a urn of size $n$ is $\frac{k}{n}$ assuming the item has probability 1 of being among the $n$